# Timezone conversion to "EDT" in Java

Tags: java, parsing, timezone

I need to get the current time in "EDT" timezone. I got the current time and formatted it into "EDT", I'm getting the time as I wanted. But when I tried to parse it into date in "EDT" timezone, still i'm getting the time in "IST" format after parsing in into date. I don't know what i'm doing wrong.

```
Date date = new Date(); 

String format = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss Z";

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format);

formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));

String dateString = formatter.format(date);
System.out.println(dateString);

try {       System.out.println(formatter.parse(dateString));
}     

catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: EDT isn't a time zone. It's *part* of Eastern time zones, but it's not in force most of the year. The man problem is that you're still printing out `Date.toString` though, which *always* uses the system default time zone. A `Date` value *doesn't have a time zone*.

Comment: Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
System.out.println(instance.getTimeZone());
System.out.println(instance.getTime());                           **Output :** Eastern Standard Time
Mon Jul 01 18:02:10 IST 2013

Comment: Presuambly "Eastern Standard Time" is the result of `TimeZone.toString()`. And the IST part is explained by my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

The java.util.Date and .Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them. Instead use either Joda-Time or the java.time package in Java 8 (inspired by Joda-Time).

Unlike a java.util.Date, a DateTime in Joda-Time knows its own assigned time zone. If you fail to specify a time zone, the JVM's default time zone will be assigned.

You can convert to and from a java.util.Date object as needed for use with other classes.

```
java.util.Date date = new Date();

DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/New_York" );
DateTime dateTimeNewYork = new DateTime( date, timeZone );
DateTime dateTimeIndia = dateTimeNewYork.withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" ) );
DateTime dateTimeUtc = dateTimeNewYork.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );
```

Call the `toString` method on those DateTime objects to see their own time zone used to generate a String using the sensible ISO 8601 standard format. You can use other formats on Joda-Time as well.